# Magento 2.1.3 billing address in checkout shipping step

Tags: magento2

The checkbox "My billing and shipping addresss are the same" is not coming in frontend. I have to show the billing address form under shipping address in shipping step Magento 2.1.3.

Comment: Please check View Source it should be there

Comment: I checked. There is no billing address fields.

Comment: Is there any settings in Backend?